# Finding from a list of patients whit multiple treatment events those who don't have an initial event

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a table with a list of patients with repeating treatment events (several thousand of records).
Eg. in the following table in column A patients are coded with numbers (the same numbers the same patient), and in column B are coded the treatment events of the patients.
I want to exclude those patients who don’t have an initial treatment event (here "a"), and to mark them in column C for example with "E".

```
A   B   C    
1   a       
1   b       
1   c       
2   b   E    
2   c   E    
3   a       
3   c       
4   a       
4   b       
5   a       
5   b       
5   c       
6   a       
6   b       
6   c       
6   d       
6   e       
6   f       
7   b   E    
7   f   E
```

Comment: Please include what you tried. We don't code for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula to put in the column C is

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$21,A2,$B$2:$B$21,"a")=0,"E","")
```

It counts the occurences of "a" treatments for each patient, and where there is none (count = 0) it puts letter E.